# Test String if each letter has '+' sign on both sides of it

Tags: javascript, regex, boolean, symbols

this program is supposed to test str, and if every letter in str has a '+' sign on both sides of it then the function should return true. Otherwise, it should return false. I keep getting the error "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier".

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
  var boolean = false;
  for(var i=1;i<(str.length-1);i++){
    if(/\w/.test(str.charAt(i))){
      if(str.charAt(i-1).match('+') && str.charAt(i+1).match('+')){
        boolean = true;
      }else{
        boolean = false;
      }
    }
  }
  str = boolean;
  return str; 

}
```

Comment: Answered a similar question in here, if you want there are some solutions http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/coderbyte-simplesymbols-challenge-in-javascript/39424#39424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match` is used for regular expressions, so it's trying to convert `'+'` to a regular expression, but it's failing because `/+/` isn't a valid regular expression (it should be `'\\+'` or `/\+/`). But it's easier to just directly test each character, like this:

```
  if(str.charAt(i-1) == '+' && str.charAt(i+1) == '+'){
```

Also note that `/\w/` matches any 'word' character, which includes letters, numbers, and underscores. To mach *just* letter characters use should use `/[a-z]/i` (the `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive, so it will also match upper-case letters).

But it seems a lot simpler to invert the condition. Just test to see if the string contains any letter *not* surrounded by `+` signs or a letter at the beginning or end of the string, and return `false` if it does, like this:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    return ! /(^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z]([^+]|$)/i.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Your inverted-condition version returns true for `"a+b"` and `"a+bb"` and `"aa+bb"`.

Comment: How's this?   'return !! /\+[a-z]\+/.test(str);'

Comment: @user3196340 That would return `true` if it contained some character sequence like `'+a+'`, anywhere in the string. It wouldn't care if other letters weren't surrounded by `+`, e.g. `/\+[a-z]\+/.test('+a+foo')` → `true`.

Comment: Now we're cooking. +1.

Comment: @p.s.w.g What does `|` do?

Comment: @user3196340 That's an alternation; you can think of it as meaning *or*. The regex engine will first try to match whatever is on the left side (within the surrounding group), and if it fails to match that, will then attempt to match whatever is on the right. For example, `/foo|bar/` will match the strings `'foo'` and `'bar'` but not `'baz'`.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    return !str.match(/[^+]\w/) && !str.match(/\w[^+]/);
}
```

Comment: This is nice and neat, but it returns true for `"a+b"` and `"2+1"`, neither of which meets the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The main problems with your function are:

1. You don't test if the first and last characters are letters. It should be safe to run your for loop from index `0` to `< str.length` because even though this will result in a `str.charAt(-1)` and `str.charAt(str.length)` when testing for `'+'` these just return `""` rather than an error. Or of course you could continue with testing from the second character through to the second last in the loop and add an additional test for the first and last characters.
2. The `.match()` method does a regex match, so it tries to convert `'+'` to a regex and of course `+` has special meaning within a regex and doesn't match the literal. I'd suggest just using `=== '+'` instead, though you could use `.match(/\+/)`.
3. You are returning whatever value the `boolean` variable ends up with, which means your function is ignoring the tests on all but the second-last character in the string. You should return `false` immediately if you find a letter that doesn't have `'+'` around it.
4. Your question asked about "letters", but `/\w/` doesn't test for a letter, it tests for letters or digits or underscores. If you actually want just letters use `/[a-z]/i`.

(Also there's no point assigning `str = boolean`, because JS function parameters are passed by value so this assignment won't affect anything outside the function.)

So:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(/[a-z]/i.test(str.charAt(i))){
      if(str.charAt(i-1)!='+' || str.charAt(i+1) != '+'){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```